# What are the curly braces inside html element in jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I came across a code sample that had the following syntax:

```
function createListing(groups, className) {

    const sharedProps = {
      title: (
        <InfoButton
          className="margin-left-1"
          data-qa={"info-button"}
        >
          {target => (
            <Toooltip
              placement="bottom"
              target={target}
            >
              {toolTipText}
            </Tooltip>
          )}
        </InfoButton>
      )
    }

      <ItemBlock key={group.title} {...sharedProps}>
        Not Available
      </ItemBlock>
}
```

I don't quite understand something that's going on with the `{target => ()}` section. What is the target variable that's passed inside `<InfoButton />`. I google searched this but can't find reference to what that syntax is. Would someone be able to explain what it is or provide a link for further reading?

Comment: @Julian No, i've seen that article but it's looks like a different use and doesn't answer my core question of the `target` variable being passed in.

Comment: You are correct. I'm sorry.

Comment: Would you mind sharing where you found the code sample?

Comment: I don't think that's valid jsx.

Comment: I can't unfortunately, it's a private repository.

Comment: @YouTwitFace It's seems to works.

Comment: I don't think this pattern has a fancier name other than what it is: "functions as child component". If you Google "react function as child component" you'll find articles with examples. Basically, it allows the wrapping component to pass on props to its children. In your example, possibly the `InfoButton` component has a ref which it wants to pass to its children. That ref isn't available outside the component, so how does it pass it down to its children? Well, it does so internally, using this technique where `target` prop is the ref (again just guessing that's the functionality)

Comment: @Jayce444 Thank You!! What a wold of difference just knowing what to google can make.

Comment: React doesn't seem to like it. ```Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.```

Comment: @YouTwitFace is the when you use a function or const component?

Comment: Good blog post on the downsides of this abstruse Function as Child Component pattern: https://americanexpress.io/faccs-are-an-antipattern/

Comment: @bos570 I put `{() =>  (<h1>Some Text</h1>)}` inside a div.